# In Android, how can I persist the information of receiving an intent?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, persistence

I have a calendar application with an overview activity. That activity shows calender entries for the current day. Only those are held in RAM, while the rest of entries sits in an SQLite file. When the user manually changes the system date, the app needs to restart the database cursor to load data for another day.

In the manifest file, I have declared a `BroadcastReceiver` that is triggered on `ACTION_DATE_CHANGED`. However, I have so far been unable to find a way to inform the responsible activity in case the receiver is triggered while the app is in background.

So far I tried to use a static flag that the receiver sets when triggered and a singleton. Both fail in the event that the process the receiver runs in dies.

How can I persist information about the receiver having been triggered until the app returns to foreground/running state?

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your intent and save/retrieve it as a string using SharedPreferences as an option.